# Meaning of Exchange in Spark Stage

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

### Can anyone explain me the meaning of exchange in my spark stages in spark DAG. Most of my stages either starts or end in exchange.

1). WholeStageCodeGen -> Exchange
2). Exchange -> WholeStageCodeGen -> SortAggregate -> Exchange

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Whole stage code generation is a technique inspired by modern compilers to collapse the entire query into a single function 
Prior to whole-stage code generation, each physical plan is a class with the code defining the execution. With whole-stage code generation, all the physical plan nodes in a plan tree work together to generate Java code in a single function for execution. This Java code is then turned into JVM bytecode using Janino, a fast Java compiler. Then JVM JIT kicks in to optimize the bytecode further and eventually compiles them into machine instructions.

For example

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [id#27, token#28, token#6]
+- *SortMergeJoin [id#27], [id#5], Inner
   :- *Sort [id#27 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#27, 200)
```

Where ever you see *, it means that wholestagecodegen has generated hand written code prior to the aggregation.
Exchange means the Shuffle Exchange between jobs.Exchange does not have whole-stage code generation because it is sending data across the network.

Comment: Did you get all this only by skimming through the source code ? This is all barely documented anywhere

Comment: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-whole-stage-codegen.html